# How to save storage by truncating datetime objects?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, hdf5, h5py

I want to save time series data in HDF5 format, using `h5py`. Since it's time series data, each row's datetime value is important, but the problem is that the column of datetime objects takes almost half the size. This is the struture of the dataset:

```
>>> arr
rec.array([('2019-11-20T13:21:08.991048000',     2, 283.  ,    1, 88.58, 331052),
           ('2019-11-20T13:21:09.194200000',     3, 282.95,   -1, 88.58, 331052),
           ('2019-11-20T13:21:09.194200000',     4, 283.  ,    1, 88.58, 331052),
           ...,
           ('2019-11-20T15:34:49.276048000', 22752, 282.6 ,    1, 94.75, 328680),
           ('2019-11-20T15:34:49.276048000', 22753, 282.6 ,    1, 94.75, 328680),
           ('2019-11-20T15:44:49.821344000', 23428, 282.65, 4814, 94.75, 327803)],
          dtype=[('index', '<M8[ns]'), ('order', '<u4'), ('value1', '<f8'), ('value2', '<i2'), ('value3', '<f4'), ('value4', '<u4')])
```

I save it in hdf5 after converting the dtype of index column into `int64` because hdf5 doesn't support `datetime`.

```
arr = arr.astype([ ('index', 'int64'), ('order', 'uint32'), ('value1', 'float64'), ('value2', 'int16'), ('value3', 'float32'), ('value4', 'uint32') ])
```

I'm going to make one dataset(array) for each day, which means that each row doesn't need to contain the same YEAR, MONTH, DAY values. I think it would be more efficient if I could add an attribute of YEAR, MONTH, DAY values to each dataset and each row had only HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND(MILLISECOND) values. Is it a possible idea? I don't mind preprocessing datasets when reading them.

Comment: Yes, if you manipulate your datetime data, you can do that. It's simpler to name the dataset with the YYYY-MM-DD value. If you want an attribute, you add them to a group or dataset with the `.attrs()` method. For example, if you have a dataset named `2019-11-20`, you could add an attribute like this `h5f['2019-11-20'].attrs['datetime']='2019-11-20'` (where h5f is your hdf5 file object). or if you want them separately: `h5f['2019-11-20'].attrs['year']=2019, h5f['2019-11-20'].attrs['month']=11, h5f['2019-11-20'].attrs['day']=20`

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you for your advice. Could you tell me what the best way would be to truncate datetime objects? I thought of just saving ```HHmmssffffff``` as uint32 and am wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Are you familiar with `datetime.strptime()`? It's method to parse strings to datetime using a standard parse format. Once it's in datetime format, you can convert into any format you want with `datetime.strftime()`. Your data almost fits the parse format of ` %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f ` Only 6 digits are accepted for the seconds fraction. So, if you trim the string as shown, it will work: `2019-11-20T13:21:08.991048`